# Surprising behavior with replicated, deleted CouchDb documents

Tags: couchdb

We have two CouchDb servers, let's call them `A` and `B`. There's one-way replication from `A` to `B` and documents are only created, modified, or deleted on `A` - basically you can think of `B` as just a backup. There was a document on `A` that was deleted. When I tried to retrieve the revision prior to deletion from `A` I got `{"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}` but that DB hasn't been compacted (at least as I understand it compaction only happens if you start it manually and that wasn't done). However, while `B` knew the document had been deleted the old revision **was** available on `B`.

My understanding is that if we haven't manually run compaction the old revision should always be available on `A`. Furthermore, when `B` replicates if there were multiple revisions since the last replication it'll pull metadata for the old revisions but might not pull the documents. Thus, in this setup, the set of revisions available on `B` should always be a proper subset of those available on `A`. So how could `B` have a revision that `A` does not?

We're on CouchDb 2.3.0.

Comment: which CouchDB version are you using?

Comment: Good question @JuanjoRodriguez. I updated my original question with that info.

Comment: Do you have any automatic compation rule configured in your A node? (https://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.3.0/config/compaction.html#compaction-daemon-rules)

Comment: yes, compaction is configured. I was under the impression that it always had to be manually triggered. That explains it, thanks. If you want to turn that into an answer I'll mark it correct.